# cPanel Mail Function

Tags: php, dns, email, cpanel

There is a wordpress installation installed on a cpanel account. They have a contact form on that wordpress installation that is sending using the php mail function. It is supposed to be sending like this:

```
noreply@cpanel_example.com -> info@cpanel_example.com
```

But it is sending like this, using the servers hostname with the cpanel username and the email account name.

```
cpanel_example@server.whm_example.com -> info@cpanel_example.com
```

What is causing this?

*Edit

So I added a plugin in WordPress which allowed the php mail function to send from `wordpress@cpanel_example.com`. I don't know how it did this though. So I feel the issue is with the default php mail function sender address.

*Edit 2 (example php code)

```
<?php
    $to      = 'info@cpanel_example.com'; 
    $subject = 'The test for php mail function'; 
    $message = 'Hello'; 
    $headers = 'From: noreply@cpanel_example.com' . "\r\n" . 
        'Reply-To: noreply@bcttransfers.com' . "\r\n" . 
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

*Edit 3 (wordpress plugin used that allowed the emails to be sent from `wordpress@cpanel_example.com`)

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

SETTINGS
From Email: BLANK (default address used: wordpress@bcttransfers.com)
Mailer: Default (none)
Return path: checked
```

Comment: I am not sure this is configurable, someone smarter than me might now.  I got around it by setting up a forwarder.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you setup the forwarder?

Comment: Does your edit indicate that you found a satisfactory solution? If not, please include your PHP code so we can see how you're sending emails. Of special attention would be the `from` address and if you're using `localhost` instead of an SMTP. Doing the later would of course use the server's host name and user the script was run under. Using an SMTP with a `from` address allowed to relay through it is what you'd want to do, and likely what the WordPress plugin probably used.

Comment: Posted the php code and the WordPress plugin used with its settings.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use the default php mail function directly sending via the webserver, you may want to configure the Wordpress site to send via SMTP.  I like to use the [Easy WP SMTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)

With the plugin enabled, your site can send emails "officially" through an SMTP enabled mail account, even it is one created in CPanel on your hosting provider.  The advantage to sending via SMTP and not directly through phpmail or sendmail is mitigating the likelihood of your messages being flagged as spam (sometimes because the shared server IPs being blacklisted, other times because of overridden email headers).

Comment: I don't want to do that. I will have 100s of sites. I just need the php mail function to send via wordpress@domain.com

Comment: if the plugin you used has a default send from address of wordpress@cpanel_example.com, chances are- you could repurpose the module and edit the php to automatically apply info@domain.com and connect via smtp (assuming you set all the info@ account passwordss with a uniform pattern).

Comment: I added some more information if that helps?